# Resetting a form generated server-side in vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I am rendering a form with Blade, Laravel's server-side templating language. The default values for the form elements are assigned by Blade. There is no JavaScript involved until now. Now I want to implement a reset button.

When a user presses the reset button the form should be cleared. A simple HTML reset button is not sufficient as it would not reset the "value=something" default values to "null".

In other words:

```
<input type="text" name="fullname" value="John Doe">
```

is supposed to be

```
<input type="text" name="fullname" value="">
```

after the user pressed the reset button.

With JQuery I would do something like this:

```
$("body").find('form').find('input').val('');
```

- How can I do it with vue.js? Adding av-model and setting the v-model properties to *null* interferes with the server side default values...
- In general: would you suggest to add a DOM manipulating lib to the application for such "hybrid" use cases where vue.js does not control the data?

Comment: How are you using vue then?

Comment: In other parts of the application I use "proper" vue.js components e.g. for autocompletion. I struggle with situations where I need only a bit of JS support, to hide/show elements in a large form, to manipulate DOM elements... I am not sure if using vue.js is the right approach for this "hybrid approach".

Comment: You can go halfway and include jquery and change the dom but that is not the intended use for vue imo. Completly possible using vannila js or even include Jquery to change the dom, but having both in a aplication seems unefficient and not that well organized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a reset-form button component. In this component I use plain Javascript to get all input, select, ... fields of the form identified by an id and reseted the values to ''.

I took this option as it was the fastest way to reset the form and I don't have to change anything (e.g. add props, change ajax calls) if my form changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on using vue, forget about altering the dom, vue works around states so imagine your input is like this

`<input type="text" v-model="test_input">`

and when you change the variable test_input the input automaticly changes its value, so just set it to empty in a method.

```
<button @click="clear_form"> Clear </button> 

<script>
export default {
   data() {
      return {
         test_input : ''
      }
   },
   methods:{
    clear_form(){
       this.test_input = '';
    }
   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I tried using v-model, but this interferes with server side default values, I can't use it.

Comment: What do you mean it interferes with server side default values?

Comment: The default values are generated server-side, let's say test_input=42. If I add a v-model and add e.g. test_input = '', test_input will be empty, not 42, as vue.js overwrites the server side default values. A possible solution would be to generate the default values in vue.js with an Ajax request... but this is much effort for just a simple reset button.. I was wondering how other poeple solve such situations.

Comment: Can't you set the default value as props when building the component? and then on mounted you say `this.test_input = this.defaultPropValue`, and on reseting, doing the same

Comment: the default value come from the database/request and the form is quite large. So it would be many props... feels quite unelegant... the more I think about it the more I think plain JS is the way to go if I want to stick to this hybrid approac.